# JavaScript & CSS - Am I doing right this way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to add 'RED' color while value comes negative and 'GREEN' color for positive value. I tried a lot to figure out why it's not working but don't get success.

Kindly correct my script. What's wrong in below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".status")
    .filter(function () {
    return $(this).html() < 0;
})
    .parent().css('color', 'blue');
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<span class="status">10</span><br />
<span class="status">-1</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```js
//run code for every element with the status class
$(".status").each(function () { 

   //cache which element is $(this) to make code load faster
   $this = $(this); 

   //cache the text of $(this)
   //parseInt() makes "text" into number so that we can use ">", "<", etc..
   number = parseInt( $this.text() ); 
   
   //if number is great than or equal to zero, make it green
   if (number >= 0) { 
     $this.css("color", "green")

   //if the number is NOT greater than or equal to zero, make it red
   } else {
     $this.css("color", "red")
   }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="status">-10</div>
<div class="status">2</div>
```

Note: this makes 0 also green.

Improving your code:

- use `[.each()][1]` so that you can run the code for every element
- use `$(this)` to select the text for *that* element

You could use `.html()` instead of `.text()` and maybe your `filter` function, but this is just how I do it :)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".status").each(function (){ //add .each

    $(this).filter(function () { //add $(this)
    return $(this).html() < 0;
})
    .css('color', 'blue'); //remove parent
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="status">-10</div>
<div class="status">2</div>
```

Comment: This would consider 0 as negative.

Comment: An explanation of why the OPs code did not work and the key point as to why yours did, e.g that there were more than one item with the id status so that you needed to iterate through them, would improve your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with your code is that you're comparing a string (the value of `html()`) to an integer. You can also simplify the code by providing a function to `addClass()` which deals with the logic. Try this:

```js
$(".status").addClass(function() {
  return parseInt($(this).html(), 10) < 0 ? 'negative' : 'positive';
});
```

```css
.positive { color: #0C0; }
.negative { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="status">10</span><br />
<span class="status">-1</span>
```

Note that this would technically consider `0` to be a 'positive' value. The logic in the `addClass()` handler function can easily be changed if you do not want that behaviour.